# How to import cv2 with python 2.7.13?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to install opencv-3.2.0 on Mac Sierra, I followed this tutorial http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/ but when I import cv2 with interpreter python I got this error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/karim/.virtualenvs/cv_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZL13pyopencv_fromIN2cv4MatxIdLi4ELi4EEEEP7_objectRKT_
  Referenced from: /Users/karim/.virtualenvs/cv_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/karim/.virtualenvs/cv_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so`

Specific 
version python : python 2.7.13, 
virtualenv name : cv_env

Comment: Try installing it without virtual environment

Comment: Same result, is there other solution to install it ?

Comment: No it can't be the same error, you must be doing something unncessary there

Comment: I got the similar output error